# Virtual device can not be deleted

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t delete virtual device from Eclipse, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978715/cant-delete-virtual-device-from-eclipse-android)

I have multiple virtual devices, some of them can't be deleted. 
The AVD manager shows an error message like this:

> The android virtual device XXX is currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted.

I'm using a mac.

**Answer ->**

Delete the folder and it's *.ini file by hand. Close the AVD manager and navigate to the .android/avd folder. You should see a folder named YourAvdName and a ini file named YourAvdName.ini. Delete both. The next time you start the AVD manager, the avd should be gone.

The .android folder can be found under %USERPROFILE%/.android on Windows-systems and in ~/.android on linux/unix/mac systems.

It's in home-folder with your name (~ is a shortcut for that). Note that files and folders which start with a dot are considered hidden. Maybe theres an option in the finder to show hidden files and folders. You should also be able to go to this android folder by opening the finder and using the Go -> Go to folder (Command+Shift+G). A small dialog should appear where you can enter a path. Enter ~/.android into it and press ok. Now you should be in that folder.

Answer (score 30):

Obviously, make sure that the AVD is really not running when you try to delete it.

If that's the case and it still doesn't work you can delete the folder and it's *.ini file by hand. Close the AVD manager and navigate to the `.android/avd` folder. You should see a folder named `YourAvdName` and a ini file named `YourAvdName.ini`. Delete both. The next time you start the AVD manager, the avd should be gone.

The `.android` folder can be found under `%USERPROFILE%/.android` on Windows-systems and in `~/.android` on linux/unix/mac systems.

Comment: I don't own a mac, so this might be slightly inaccurate: It's in your home-folder with your name *(`~` is a shortcut for that)*. Note that files and folders which start with a dot are considered hidden. Maybe theres an option in the finder to show hidden files and folders. You should also be able to go to this android folder by opening the finder and using the `Go -> Go to folder` (`Command+Shift+G`). A small dialog should appear where you can enter a path. Enter `~/.android` into it and press ok. Now you should be in that folder.

Comment: Thanks alextsc. it works successfully.
I just put ~/.android in finder and it gives me the avd folder.
now m able to delete my avd's.
Thanks.