# Android DDMS devices list contains an extra unknown device in IntelliJ AS, how to delete it?

Tags: android, ddms, device, bluestacks

I installed Android Studio (intelliJ) and if I run it, in Android DDMS's Devices list is not empty. There is an unknown device, name 'Emulator unknown Android 2.3.4 (API 10)'.
If I use AVD and run my emulator, there will be two emulator in this list.

It's very annoying, because when I run an android project, accidentally select this unknown device, and it's mean my app run in nowhere. There is no GUI for this unknown, and it infinitely spam the logcat. So I want stop and delete it.

I cannot find solution in the web (but probably I used wrong keywords).

Comment: Did you try to delete the avd device ? Maybe you can check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978715/cant-delete-virtual-device-from-eclipse-android

Comment: Yeah, I tried. But this mysterious device is not in the list of AVD manager! It's only in the list of Android Studio (IntelliJ) at the right, bottom corner, when you are in tab 'android'. And if you run a project, it want to run in this non-existent device in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was the problem.
Long time ago I installed an android emulator **BlueStacks**. Currently it's not working because it was much faster then Goggle version and Google sue them. But somehow the *Android Studio* recognize it as an incomplete but running emulator.
I guess, I have to uninstall BlueStacks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a series of unknown emulators present in the "Choose Device" dialog:

[image: Multiple ADB instances]

Restarting ADB clears these.

To Restart ADB:

1. In the bottom left corner of the screen, click the square box, and choose *Terminal*.

   [image: Starting the Terminal Window]
2. In the Terminal, type `adb kill-server`, and press ENTER

   [image: Restarting ADB]
3. Re-start the Android application ([image]), which will bring up the Choose Devices dialog again. The extra emulators will have disappeared.

Unfortunately, this is a temporary fix, as, over time, these will reappear again.

*Note: I didn't have BlueStacks installed.*